# Apache2 cannot proxy Grafana websocket connection?

Tags: apache, websocket, proxy, apache2, grafana

My Grafana `[server]` config looks like:

```
[server]
protocol = http

http_addr = 127.0.0.1

http_port = 3000

domain = localhost

root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
```

And my Apache2 proxy looks like:

```
...

<VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    SSLEngine on

    ...

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location /grafana/>
         ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
         ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    </Location>

    <Location /grafana/api/live>
         RequestHeader set Host $http_host
         RequestHeader set Upgrade $http_upgrade
         RequestHeader set Connection "Upgrade"

         ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/live
         ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/live
    </Location>

...
```

But in a browser I still see: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-host.com/grafana/api/live/ws' failed:`

And `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log` says that:

```
logger=context userId=0 orgId=1 uname= t=2024-02-16T22:29:01.895505416Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/live/ws status=400 remote_addr=169.45.10.55 time_ms=1 duration=1.870792ms size=12 referer= handler=/api/live/ws
```